Regions that a function of three variables is positive
I have a function $u(bb,GG,s)$. I want to find the regions where this function is positive for all values of s between 0.01 and 10. The other two variables bb and GG vary in the intervals $0.01<bb<4$ and $0.01<GG<4$.
My function is
us[bb_, GG_, s_] := ((
a[GG, bb]  bb - a[GG, bb]  bb  E^(-(s/bb)) + 1 - E^-s)/(
1 + a[GG, bb] ));

where
    a[GG_, bb_] := (
   1 - Pnn (EulerGamma + PolyGamma[0, GG]))/(-1 + 
   bb  Pnn (EulerGamma + PolyGamma[0, GG/bb]));

and Pnn=0.9;
I the function was only a function of two variables, I could used region plot, but I do not know how to plot regions that are positive for all values of s.  Could someone please help me?

$Version

(* "14.1.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 16, 2024)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

Pnn = 9/10;

a[GG_, bb_] = (1 - Pnn (EulerGamma + PolyGamma[0, GG]))/(-1 + 
     bb Pnn (EulerGamma + PolyGamma[0, GG/bb]));

us[bb_, GG_, 
   s_] = ((a[GG, bb] bb - a[GG, bb] bb E^(-(s/bb)) + 1 - E^-s)/(1 + 
      a[GG, bb]));

rgnPlt = RegionPlot3D[
    us[GG, bb, s] > 0,
    {bb, 1/100, 4}, {GG, 1/100, 4}, {s, 1/100, 10},
    PlotStyle -> Directive[LightBlue, Opacity[0.75]],
    Mesh -> None,
    PlotPoints -> 125,
    WorkingPrecision -> 50,
    AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {bb, GG, s}),
    ViewPoint -> {0, 0, 100}] // Quiet;

To display the region along with a check at a specified point:
Manipulate[
 Column[{
   Show[rgnPlt,
    Graphics3D[{Red, AbsoluteThickness[4],
      Line[{{b, g, 1/100}, {b, g, 10}}]}],
    ImageSize -> 400],
   Plot[us[g, b, s], {s, 1/100, 10},
    AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {s, HoldForm[us[GG, bb, s]]}),
    ImageSize -> 300]}],
 {{g, 2, "GG"}, 0.01, 4, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{b, 2, "bb"}, 0.01, 4, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 SynchronousUpdating -> False,
 TrackedSymbols :> {g, b}]


The lighter blue region of the RegionPlot is where us[GG, bb, s] > 0 for all 1/100 < s < 10

I'm not sure that it's helpful, but you can write:
r = ImplicitRegion[
us[bb, GG, s] > 0, {{bb, 0.01, 4}, {GG, 0.01, 4}, {s, 0.01, 10}}];

Then get something to visualise using
Region[r]

There might be some options giving a higher quality output, but I haven't identified them.

RegionPlot3D[us[GG, bb, s] > 0, {bb, 1/100, 4}, {GG, 1/100, 4}, {s, 1/100, 10},  PlotPoints -> 100, WorkingPrecision -> 25, AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {bb, GG, s})]//Quiet

thanks. but the question is about "positive for all values of s". I need a two dimensional map that shows where the function is positive as a function of b and gg.

@BobHanlon thanks. but the question is about "positive for all values of s". I need a two dimensional map that shows where the function is positive as a function of b and gg.
